# How to return the element of an array containing the max value (index 1) (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript

Given the array below, how can I return the element containing the max number?

```
let ar = [["finalOrderData",1],["finalFabricData",3],["finalDecorationData",3],["finalHtData",3]]
```

**Expected Result**

```
let ar = ["finalFabricData",3]
```

This is the function I'm trying with, but it only returns the number itself:

```
function getMaxOf2DIndex(arr, idx) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, arr.map(function (e) { return e[idx] }))
}
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Why wouldn't it return all the objects with `3`? What if the objects were in a different order - would it still be index 1 that you'd want?

Comment: I would only need to get the first/largest dataset and its name. The others will be concatenated later on. Thanks for your comment, @Andy!

Comment: but your expected result is the last largest dataset, instead of the first...?

Comment: This is an array of arrays. which index 1 are you trying to get?
Index 1 of the outer layer is an array ``["finalFabricData",3]`` , the index 1 of the inner arrays is a number

Comment: Just made some corrections so that this is clear. Sorry...all day looking at code and learning...and all shimmers to my eyes now. Thanks, @Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```js
let ar = [['finalOrderData', 1], ['finalFabricData', 3], ['finalDecorationData', 3], ['finalHtData', 3]];

let res = ar.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])[0];

console.log(res);
```

Note that this doesn't handle the alphabetical order of the word.

Comment: Not a bad answer, but the space complexity isn't the best since sort will return a sorted copy of the original array. The reduce answer below is a bit better in this regard.

Comment: @sleepystar96 the (auxiliary) space complexity is `O(1)` here. `.sort()` doesn't return a copy of the original array, it sorts the original array and returns a reference to that same array. I do agree though that the other answers are a bit better due to their time complexity. This has a tc of `O(nlogn)`, whereas the other loop/reduce approaches are more scalable for larger arrays as they're doing one-pass over the array, so they're a linear`O(n)` :).

Comment: Ah you're right, I missed that JS Array.sort() sorts in-place. Thanks for correcting me!

Comment: Missed it even though it's literally the first line in the MDN documentation haha. Also, thank you for pointing out the other disadvantages of using sort to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function

```js
let ar = [["finalOrderData",1],["finalFabricData",3],["finalDecorationData",3],["finalHtData",3]]
let result = ar.reduce((acc,cur) => !acc || cur[1] > acc[1] ? cur : acc, undefined);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Good answer! I think you can initialize reduce with the first item in `ar` though, that way you can get rid of the undefined check.

Answer (score 3):

```js
    function getMaxOf2DIndex(arr, idx) {
    let maxItem = arr[0];
    
    arr.forEach((item, i) => {
        if(item[idx] >= maxItem[idx])
            maxItem = item; 
    });
    
    return maxItem;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the most straightforward way:

```
let ar = [["finalOrderData",1],["finalFabricData",3],["finalDecorationData",3],["finalHtData",3]]

var maxNumber = ar[0]

ar.forEach((element) => maxNumber = element[1] > maxNumber[1] ? element : maxNumber)
```

or the same written more verbosely:

```
let ar = [["finalOrderData",1],["finalFabricData",3],["finalDecorationData",3],["finalHtData",3]]

var maxNumber = ar[0]

for (element of ar) {

  let number = element[1]

  if (number > maxNumber[1])
    maxNumber = number
  }
```

Comment: But what if you don't know the first instance of the max number is at index 1?

Comment: Not sure what you mean @Andy, the number is always at index 1 in `ar`.

Comment: I misread; my answer doesn't return the original array containing the max number, just the max number. Edit: fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 examples:

```js
const ar = [
  ["finalOrderData",1],
  ["finalFabricData",3],
  ["finalDecorationData",3],
  ["finalHtData",3]
]

// the 1st result of the biggest value:
const output1 = ar.sort((A,B) => B[1] - A[1])[0]

console.log(output1)
// output: ["finalFabricData",3]

// the last result of the biggest value:
const output2 = ar.sort((A,B) => B[1] <= A[1] ? -1 : 1)[0]

console.log(output2)
// output: ["finalHtData",3]
```

Answer (score 0):

one more Solution using Array.reduce:

```
ar.reduce((res, val) => Math.max(res[1],val[1]) === res[1] ?  res : val  );
```

trick here is to check with already calculated result.